# T-SQL : must declare scalar variable - error in while loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the many changes, here now the full Code, that produces the error, I think it comes from all the "Where ID = @currID" Statements, but I dont know how to improve that. Also thankfull for any other suggestions to improve the Code, as I am a beginner, thanks a lot!

```
DECLARE @currID bigint
SET @currID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM dbo.test1);
WHILE (@currID <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.test1))
BEGIN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.test2 
        WHERE A = (SELECT A FROM dbo.test1 WHERE ID = @currID) 
        AND B = (SELECT B FROM dbo.test1 WHERE ID = @currID))

                UPDATE dbo.test2
                SET Count = Count + (SELECT Count FROM dbo.test1 WHERE ID = @currID)
                WHERE A = (SELECT A FROM dbo.test1 WHERE ID = @currID) 
                AND B = (SELECT B FROM dbo.test1 WHERE ID = @currID);

                SET @currID = @currID + 1

        ELSE
                INSERT INTO dbo.test2 (A, B)
                SELECT *
                FROM dbo.test1 WHERE ID = @currID;

                SET @currID = @currID + 1

END
```

Comment: These types of errors are generally always due to a typo. You just need to inspect the code carefully and ensure that variables are spelled correctly and parens are in the correct spots.

Comment: Aside: `{` and `}`? It doesn't look like you're using [ODBC escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). Possible typo: `Eventlogs_Aggregated_byTime1` and `Eventlogs_Aggregatet_byTime1 `.

Comment: I see at least three places where that's invalid t-sql.

Comment: You have changed the code in the question 3 or 4 times now, which makes it impossible for anyone to provide a meaningful answer. Please can you post the **entire** code you are trying to run, and the **exact** error message that you are getting?

Comment: @GarethD sorry for the inconvenience, I have updated the Code. The error is in German so translated it is just the caption of this post (Error Code: 137) at WHILE

Comment: Debugging tip: Drop your code sample into SSMS and then click on the checkbox button (Parse, aka Ctrl+F5). It will show that the `else` syntax is incorrect. That's because a `set` statement can't have an `else`. A `begin`/`end` pair around all of the statements in the `if` is needed. Based on the indentation of the code you probably have the same (silent) error on the `else` clause: only the `insert` is part of the `else`, the `set` is a separate statement that follows the `if`/`else`.

Comment: This loop is just a less-efficient cursor. So either use a cursor (sometimes it is an appropriate solution) or convert your logic into a set-based solution (and it is likely you can do this). Notice your assumption - that there are no gaps in the values for test1.ID. In this case you are lucky that your insert logic will not accidentally insert a non-existing value.

Comment: I'll add that a column named "count" is just a terrible and confusing choice for a name. I'm hoping that you did not desire to actually count rows but it is impossible to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: Issue were the simicolons, which symbolize a new block in which old local variables are not available anymore and there need to be "begin" and "end" after each "if" and "else"

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the subquery. The batch

```
DECLARE @currID bigint
SET @currID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM dbo.Eventlogs_Aggregated_byTime1)
WHILE (@currID < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.Eventlogs_Aggregated_byTime1) + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the error is somewhere else...

Comment: Bad parentheses. The  + 1 shouldn't be part of the statement, corrected.